# Next time, I'll treat you in another way

Tags: sentence-construction, idiomatic-language, sentence-request

Imagine two guys are fighting and A has grabbed B by the collar.

> B: let it go 
>   A: Hey, I'll excuse you this time! Make sure this will not happen again! **Next time, I'll treat you in another way**.

I wonder if the bold statement above sounds correct English, If not then please let me know how should I say that?

Comment: That preposition **in** seems to be redundant!

Comment: "differently" would be more likely than "in another way". The rest of it doesn't sound very idiomatic, though.

Comment: @Jack O'Flashery then how would you phrase it in everyday informal speech?

Comment: Well, you don't have an almost fight every day, but... "I'll let it go this time, but make sure it doesn't happen again, or I'll teach you a lesson you wont forget." The possibilities are limitless.

Comment: Thank you, but I need to know how shall I rephrase "Next time, I'll treat you in another way" @Jack O'Flaherty.

Comment: As I said already, "Next time I'll treat you differently."

Answer (score -1):

A is saying that next time he's gonna treat (beat/fight/hurt) B in another way

This time A slapped B next time he will kick/punch B

Comment: But your answer is against what @Jack O'Flaherty as a native speaker mentioned.

Comment: He's saying right, i told you differently